# How to make a mocked object's arbitrary nested attributes/methods to return specific values in Python?

Tags: python, mocking

Let's say I am creating a mock object:

```py
mocked = MagicMock()
```

And I would like to set this `mocked` instance's all arbitrary nested attributes/methods to return specific values:

```py
mocked = MagicMock()
# mock.all_return_value = 'expected'
# so calling the following will return `expected`
mocked.a.b.c.d()
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to subclass and override [_get_child_mock()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock._get_child_mock).

It is designed for subclasses to override to return customized values for properties:

> **_get_child_mock(**kw)**
>
> Create the child mocks for attributes and return value. By default child mocks will be the same type as the parent.
>   Subclasses of Mock may want to override this to customize the way
>   child mocks are made.

If you make it return a new instance and set the `return_value` you should get the effect you want:

```
class NestMock(MagicMock):
    def _get_child_mock(self, **kw):
        return NestMock(return_value = kw['parent'].return_value)


m = NestMock(return_value="expected")
m()               # 'expected'
m.a.b()           # 'expected'
m.call_count      # 1
m.a.b.call_count  # 1
m.c.call_count    # 0
```